# cartItems.map is not a function in Redux

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux

Earlier I had got an error, and the error was that I had to add items.length>0 to wait for it. Again I have done something similar but it shows an error

Error

```
TypeError: cartItems.map is not a function
CartScreen
E:/College/DA/IWP/Book Fair/frontend/src/Screens/CartPage.js:35
  32 |     <div>Cost</div>
  33 | </li>
  34 | {
> 35 |     cartItems.length == 0?<div>Empty...</div>:
     | ^  36 |     cartItems.map(book => 
  37 |         <div >
  38 |             <img src = {book.image} alt = {book.name}/>
```

CartPage.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { AddToCart } from '../actions/cartActions';
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux';

function CartScreen(props){

    // get cart items from redux store

    const cart = useSelector(state => state.cart);

     //From cart get cartItems

    const cartItems = cart;
    console.log(cartItems);

    // Get book id, so we know what is added
    const bookId = props.match.params.id;
    const qty = props.location.search?Number(props.location.search.split("=")[1]):1;
    const dispatch=useDispatch();
    useEffect(() =>{
        if(bookId){
            dispatch(AddToCart(bookId, qty));

        }
    },[])


    return <div className="cartPage">
        {/* <div className="cartList">
            <ul className="container">
                <li> 
                    <h2>Your Cart</h2>
                    <div>Cost</div>
                </li>
                {
                    cartItems.length == 0?<div>Empty...</div>:
                    cartItems.map(book => 
                        <div >
                            <img src = {book.image} alt = {book.name}/> 
                            <div className = "Details">
                            <div>{book.name}</div>
                            <div> Quantity:
                                <select>
                                    <option value = "1">1</option>
                                    <option value = "2">2</option>
                                    <option value = "3">3</option>
                                    <option value = "4">4</option>

                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                        <div> {book.cost}</div>  
                         </div>
                        

                        )
                }
            </ul>
            
            
        </div>
        <div className="cartButton">

        </div> */}
    </div>
}

export default CartScreen;
```

I have created a CartPage.js which is the main screen, CartAction.js which has the action, CartReducers.js
I have tried changing everything but still can't get it right

Answer (score 0):

as i can see your default state of redux is this: `state={cartItems:[]}` and you're trying to access it with `const cartItems = cart`. you need to use object destructing for getting your cart items. because your cart after using useSelector is this:`cart={cartItems:[]}`

Just change your CartPage.js and replace this line: `const {cartItems} = cart`.
Let's see if it works. Good luck@

P.S: If you want to save your cart directly and reformat it from this `cart={cartItems:[]}` to this `cart=[]` yous should change your reducer. first step is setting your default state to `state=[]` and so on...